# Response.Files is empty when using file upload from hidden iframe

Tags: c#, ajax, iframe

I'm using a hidden iframe to upload file and try to catch it from a aspx's Page_Load.

```
<input type="file" id="flAddRequestFile" name="RequestFileUpload" />
```

js is like:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');
$("body").append(iframe);
var form = $('#frm1');
form.attr("action", "/PresentationLayer/NewRequestFileUploadDialog.aspx");
form.attr("method", "post");
form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("target", "postiframe");
form.attr("file", $('#flAddRequestFile').val());
form.submit();
```

In the code behind of NewRequestFileUploadDialog.aspx I'm not getting anything under `Request.Files`. There is no header at all.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to recreate your situation and I got it to work. The only difference I have from what you have is in the JS:  after `form.submit();` I added a `return false;` to prevent the default post-back.

So, the updated JS looks like this (I assume you have this logic in an event handler like `change()` on `flAddRequestFile` or `click()` for some button):

```
var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');
 $("body").append(iframe);
 var form = $('#frm1');
 form.attr("action", "/PresentationLayer/NewRequestFileUploadDialog.aspx");
 form.attr("method", "post");
 form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
 form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
 form.attr("target", "postiframe");
 form.attr("file", $('#flAddRequestFile').val());
 form.submit();

 //this is what I added
 return false;
```